# Zooming an UIImageView that contains subviews

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, uiimageview, zooming

I have an `UIImageView` object in `UIScrollView`(to zoom). In addition, `UIImageView` also contains subviews. I am using following function to zoom in `UIImageView`.

```
func viewForZooming(in scrollView: UIScrollView) -> UIView? {
    return self.imageView
}
```

It works perfectly fine for `UIImageView`.

The problem is when zooming these subviews, it also zooms these subviews the same way. Is there a way to disable zooming for these subviews?

Comment: Why don't you just put them outside the scroll view? Or in another scroll view above the first one with transparent background?

Comment: @MaticOblak I need subviews' positions in image view.

Comment: Then I don’t understand what is your question. Like when image zooms the subviews should change positions but they should not change their size? Kind of like annotations on map; when you zoom in they still point on the same position map but they do not increase in size? You could use “convert” methods from UIView. Convert original coordinates from image view to the superview of your scrollview and move your annotations there. Just update position on scrollViewDidScroll

Comment: Yes, exactly like annotations on map. I will try, thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many ways to achieve this. I would say the easiest one is to simply back-scale your views. This is what I used as a demo:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet private var scrollView: UIScrollView?
    private var imageView: UIImageView?
    private var annotations: [UIView] = [UIView]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let imageView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "background"))
        scrollView?.addSubview(imageView)
        scrollView?.contentSize = imageView.bounds.size
        scrollView?.maximumZoomScale = 5.0
        self.imageView = imageView

        scrollView?.delegate = self

        applyAnnotationView({
            let view = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: 10.0, height: 10.0))
            view.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
            view.layer.cornerRadius = view.bounds.width*0.5
            return view
        }(), at: CGPoint(x: 100.0, y: 100.0))

        applyAnnotationView({
            let view = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: 10.0, height: 10.0))
            view.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
            view.layer.cornerRadius = view.bounds.width*0.5
            return view
        }(), at: CGPoint(x: 200.0, y: 200.0))
    }

    func applyAnnotationView(_ view: UIView, at position: CGPoint) {
        view.center = position
        annotations.append(view)
        imageView?.addSubview(view)
    }

}

// MARK: - UIScrollViewDelegate

extension ViewController: UIScrollViewDelegate {

    func scrollViewDidZoom(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        annotations.forEach { item in
            item.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1.0/scrollView.zoomScale, y: 1.0/scrollView.zoomScale)
        }
    }

    func viewForZooming(in scrollView: UIScrollView) -> UIView? {
        return imageView
    }

}
```

Simply applying `CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1.0/scrollView.zoomScale, y: 1.0/scrollView.zoomScale)` does all the work. It should be OK even when using constraints.

Answer (score 0):

The UIView, which is inside the UIImageView, will always be the same size, but will be anchored to a specific point in the image (10% at the top and 10% at the left):

```
var item: UIView?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    ...
    item = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 200))
    setPosition()
    item?.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
    imageView.addSubview(item!)
    ...
}

func setPosition() {
    let x = imageView.frame.size.width/10
    let y = imageView.frame.size.height/10
    item?.frame = CGRect(x: x, y: y, width: 200, height: 200)
}

func scrollViewDidZoom(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    ...
    setPosition()
    ...
}
```

Instead of 10%, you can use the exact figure, using the formula:

```
x = startPosition/startWidthImage*currentWidthImage
```